# Is it 'correct' to use a model in a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've recently been using rails for a new project and have tried to keep it as organised as possible. One of the things people say you shouldn't do is use the model directly in the view.

However I have various lists of items that need to be pulled into the view and it seems pointless having a long list of instance variables like:

```
@admin_list = User.all.map {|x| {id: x.id, name:x.name}}
```

So I put the above into a helper method:

```
def admin_user_list
  User.all.map {|x| {id: x.id, name:x.name}}
end
```

Should I be using a model in a helper class?

Comment: I personaly prefer decorators for such tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes thats fine, however if you find yourself using tons of methods as helpers, consider organising them into a separate class, either as a "presenter" class or a "calculation" class. If you have a sure map of where your application is headed then go ahead and do so.

Either way, you are correct in the sense that you should not be using methods like map in defining your instance variables. ( I would believe that it was defined as such in the controller?)

Anyway, if you wanted to do what you specified in the above,

```
def admin_user_list
  User.all.map {|x| {id: x.id, name:x.name}}
end
```

should really be (under the User model):

```
def self.admin_user_list
  all.map {|x| {id: x.id, name:x.name}}
end
```

otherwise you would be calling

user = User.find(1)

user.admin_user_list, which wouldn't make sense unless there are user specific admin lists, in which case I retract my statement.

An example of a separate class:

```
class Admin
def user_list
  User.all.map {|x| {id: x.id, name:x.name}}
end

@admin_list = Admin.user_list
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty opinionated question, but personally I would define this as a class method on the User class and call it as `User.admin_list`

On a side note you should ask yourself if it's actually neccessary to map your objects into a hash like you are doing.

Comment: `On a side note you should ask yourself if it's actually neccessary to map your objects into a hash like you are doing.`

Not sure what else to do in this situation as I only want the ID and name

Comment: Use the full object? I don't see any reason why you should pull it's state into a hash, just because you are only using a subset of it's attributes.

Comment: @andy you can [select specific fields](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields): `User.select(:id, :name)`

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using a model within a helper class.
You can do 2 things.... 
1.) First you can use a model class method and call User.admin_list as suggested by Niels B, but I would not suggest using this as it needs to mention model class name User in view code.

2.) You should write a method in controller and declare that as a helper method, this will allow you to directly call helper method without mentioning model class name. something like following...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 helper_method :admin_list

 def admin_list
   User.all.map {|x| {id: x.id, name:x.name}}
 end
end
```

Comment: I didn't tell him to reference the class in the view. `@admin_hashes = User.admin_list` in the controller works for me. I am, however, not a fan of mapping the model instance into a hash.